# How to filter data with pandas and convert it to a list?

Tags: python, pandas

This is one of the questions and tasks that I must do the most in my day.

I have the following dataframe columns:

```
USER_ID, BRAND_ID, CLICKS
1, 100, 50
2, 120, 40
1, 200, 4
....
```

And I need to convert it into a list, for example for user 1

```
[100, 200]
```

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in df.groupby('USER_IF')['BRAND_ID']}`

Comment: You want to make a dict with `USER_ID` as key, `BRAND_ID` as values, and throw away `CLICKS`?

Comment: Yes, correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's think that we have already read a CVS file through pandas

```
path = 'data/users_clicks.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

And then you have the following columns:

```
USER_ID, BRAND_ID, CLICKS
1, 100, 50
2, 120, 40
1, 200, 4
....
```

And once we have that data we want to group it by the user and convert it into a list, to later handle that result, for example adding it to a user dictionary.

To be able to filter it by pandas and not use for, we do:

```
user_list = df[df['USER_ID'] == 1]
print(user_list['BRAND_ID'].tolist())
```

The result is:

```
[100, 200]
```

This way you save a lot of iterative code and use Pandas to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Group by on `USER_ID` and select the `BRAND_ID`, aggregated to a list:

```py
df.groupby('USER_ID')['BRAND_ID'].agg(list)

# Gives:
USER_ID
1    [100, 200]
2         [120]
Name:  BRAND_ID, dtype: object
```

Convert that to a `dict` to get it in the form `{USER_ID: [list of BRAND_IDS]}` for all users:

```py
user_brands = df.groupby('USER_ID')['BRAND_ID'].agg(list).to_dict()

# {1: [100, 200], 2: [120]}
```

And then to get it for just user `1`:

```py
user_brands[1]

# [100, 200]
```